# Display XML content inside a GridView (Windows Form)

Tags: c#, xml, gridview

Ive been trying to display every content of a selected xml file inside a gridview on a Windows Form, but for some reason, only the content of the first parent node is shown (Playlist). I cant find a solution for this.

Heres my code:

```
private void OpenMontagem_btn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fileContent = string.Empty;
        var filePath = string.Empty;

        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Playlist\pgm\Montagem\";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                {
                    fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            ds.ReadXml(filePath);
            MontagemGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
```

Heres a piece of the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Playlist CompactMode="1">
    <Break0000M Ins="14" Locked="0" Changed="0" Filetime="2021-09-28T06:11:23.509Z" Filetime2="2021-09-22T21:18:17.190Z" Time="2021-09-29T00:00:00.000Z" Type="2" Id="" Id_Edited="" Fixo="0" Descarte="0" Net="1" Dur="0" Slots="3" Orig="00:00 &quot;Jane's Addiction - Jane Says (ao vivo).mp3&quot;, &quot;G. Love - Home.mp3&quot;, &quot;Mumford &amp; Sons - Hopeless Wanderer.mp3&quot;, &quot;BACHMAN TURNER OVERDRIVER = HEY YOY.mp3&quot;, &quot;Maná - Labios Compartidos.mp3&quot;, &quot;MAGIC! - No Way No.mp3&quot;, &quot;Maneva - Eu Te Devoro - Ao Vivo.mp3&quot;, &quot;3 Doors Down - Behind those eyes.mp3&quot;, &quot;Queen – Bohemian Rhapsody.mp3&quot;, &quot;Sleeping At Last - Saturn.mp3&quot;, &quot;BAD COMPANY - IF YOU NEED SOMEBODY.mp3&quot;, &quot;Justin Timberlake - Mirrors.mp3&quot;, &quot;Avril Lavigne - Girlfriend.mp3&quot;, &quot;Maneva - O Vento - Ao Vivo.mp3&quot;, ">
        <Ins0 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="Jane's Addiction - Jane Says (ao vivo)" File="Jane's Addiction - Jane Says (ao vivo).mp3" Folder="Rock" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2011-21-10T14:08:47" HoraPK="2021-23-09T15:43:21" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="384773" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="377680" MxIni="5003" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="128" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins1 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="G. Love - Home" File="G. Love - Home.mp3" Folder="Rock" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2011-10-06T03:22:56" HoraPK="2021-23-09T15:41:50" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="219874" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="211706" MxIni="0" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="320" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins2 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="Mumford &amp; Sons - Hopeless Wanderer" File="Mumford &amp; Sons - Hopeless Wanderer.mp3" Folder="Alternativa" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2021-23-09T15:19:50" HoraPK="2021-23-09T15:27:29" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="307999" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="301840" MxIni="0" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="128" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins3 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="BACHMAN TURNER OVERDRIVER = HEY YOY" File="BACHMAN TURNER OVERDRIVER = HEY YOY.mp3" Folder="Flashback" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2011-17-11T18:40:01" HoraPK="2021-23-09T15:44:14" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="207621" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="199447" MxIni="0" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="64" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins4 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="Maná - Labios Compartidos" File="Maná - Labios Compartidos.mp3" Folder="Pop" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2021-23-09T15:19:51" HoraPK="2021-23-09T15:30:11" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="315004" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="305559" MxIni="4027" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="128" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins5 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="MAGIC! - No Way No" File="MAGIC! - No Way No.mp3" Folder="Pop" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2021-23-09T15:19:53" HoraPK="2021-23-09T15:29:37" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="229441" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="225609" MxIni="417" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="128" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins6 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="Maneva - Eu Te Devoro - Ao Vivo" File="Maneva - Eu Te Devoro - Ao Vivo.mp3" Folder="Reggae" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2021-22-09T15:10:24" HoraPK="2021-22-09T18:06:36" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="240298" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="234308" MxIni="0" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="320" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins7 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="3 Doors Down - Behind those eyes" File="3 Doors Down - Behind those eyes.mp3" Folder="Rock" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2012-06-03T16:33:26" HoraPK="2021-22-09T18:05:27" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="254630" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="247461" MxIni="886" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="160" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins8 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="Queen – Bohemian Rhapsody" File="Queen – Bohemian Rhapsody.mp3" Folder="Rock" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2021-22-09T16:11:40" HoraPK="2021-22-09T18:06:13" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="24" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="0" MxIni="0" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="112" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins9 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="Sleeping At Last - Saturn" File="Sleeping At Last - Saturn.mp3" Folder="Alternativa" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2021-23-09T13:36:15" HoraPK="2021-23-09T13:36:41" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="285272" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="277453" MxIni="10976" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="128" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins10 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="BAD COMPANY - IF YOU NEED SOMEBODY" File="BAD COMPANY - IF YOU NEED SOMEBODY.mp3" Folder="Flashback" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2011-21-10T14:07:14" HoraPK="2021-23-09T15:44:16" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="255043" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="246876" MxIni="0" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="256" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins11 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="Justin Timberlake - Mirrors" File="Justin Timberlake - Mirrors.mp3" Folder="Pop" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2021-23-09T15:19:53" HoraPK="2021-23-09T15:29:23" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="481519" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="477049" MxIni="0" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="128" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins12 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="Avril Lavigne - Girlfriend" File="Avril Lavigne - Girlfriend.mp3" Folder="Pop Rock" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2014-27-05T20:54:31" HoraPK="2021-22-09T18:06:25" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="214194" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="212615" MxIni="1032" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="160" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins13 Id="" CTA="" Source="M" Type="M;F;" Title="Maneva - O Vento - Ao Vivo" File="Maneva - O Vento - Ao Vivo.mp3" Folder="Reggae" Text="" Composer="" Comment="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2021-22-09T15:10:24" HoraPK="2021-22-09T18:06:42" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="202162" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="201789" MxIni="0" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="320" Reg="0"/>
    </Break0000M>
    <Break0058C Ins="3" Locked="0" Changed="0" Filetime="2021-09-24T17:15:19.255Z" Filetime2="2021-09-22T21:20:18.519Z" Time="2021-09-29T00:58:00.000Z" Type="1" Id="" Id_Edited="" Fixo="0" Descarte="0" Net="1" Dur="0" Slots="3" Orig="00:58 3, 9, 4">
        <Ins0 Id="3" CTA="" Source="C" Type="C;" Title="Banco Santander Ser Dono" File="Banco Santander Ser Dono.MP3" Folder="Comerciais" Text="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2018-09-04T17:01:06" HoraPK="2021-01-05T03:03:20" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="28701" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="28357" MxIni="0" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="128" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins1 Id="9" CTA="" Source="C" Type="C;" Title="Claro" File="Claro.MP3" Folder="Comerciais" Text="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2018-09-04T15:05:35" HoraPK="2018-10-04T13:08:36" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="29920" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="28664" MxIni="512" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="128" Reg="0"/>
        <Ins2 Id="4" CTA="" Source="C" Type="C;" Title="Bobs Hino dos Lambuzados" File="Bobs Hino dos Lambuzados.MP3" Folder="Comerciais" Text="" Checked="1" Err="0" sErr="" HoraAudio="2018-10-04T17:13:21" HoraPK="2021-15-06T14:03:51" IsAudioFile="1" Dur="60600" Refr="0" DurRefr="0" PtVh="0" PtMx="60200" MxIni="456" Intro="0" PtLoc="0" Vol="0" Bitrate="128" Reg="0"/>
    </Break0058C>
</Playlist>
```

If I change ds.Tables[0] to ds.Tables[1] it shows every node with the name of Ins0

Is there a way to structure and display every bit of content inside the gridview?

Comment: You have fragmented results.  Check you ds.  You have multiple tables with fragmented pieces of the xml that can't be put back together.  You cannot use ds.ReadXml() when the number of descendants in the xml exceeds four.  The root tag with ReadXml is becomes the dataset name.  The next array of tags in the xml are the table names.  The third level tags in the xml becomes the column names.  The 4th level tags in the xml are the row data

Comment: I see, is there any other way to display this particular xml file in that format into the gridview then? I need the Break table to separate the ins between then and the ins as rows with their attributes as columns.

Comment: I added code below.  I didn't check the code thoroughly and may have a couple of typos in column names.  Should be easy to fix.  I put all data into one table but you can put into multiple tables and then use JOIN to combine tables.

Comment: Wow this is amazing mate, thank you for the help. Just one thing, when I try to display that chunk of the xml, it work just great, but when I try to use the whole xml which contains more Break tables like those two, it return the exception System.Xml.XmlException: ''.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 3, position 1.'. Can't seem to find value on said line.

Comment: I changed two line of code to find PlayList and then enumerate through the elements in playList.

Comment: The except is occurring because code was looking for first element in the document which did not have the attribute Id.  When I was writing the code I got same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication27
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Break Folder", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Ins", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Locked", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Changed", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("FileTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Filetime2", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Folder_Type", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Folder_Id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Id_Edited", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Fixo", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Descarte", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Net", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Break Dur", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Slots", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Orig", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("CTA", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Soruce", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Folder", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Composer", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Checked", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Err", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("sErr", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("HoraAudio", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("HoraPK", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("IsAudioFile", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Dur", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Refr", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DurRefr", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("PtVh", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("OtMx", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("MxIni", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Intro", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("PtLoc", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Vol", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Bitrate", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Reg", typeof(int));

            XElement playList = doc.Descendants("Playlist").FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (XElement brk in playList.Elements())                {
                string breakFolder = brk.Name.LocalName;
                int ins = (int)brk.Attribute("Ins");
                int locked = (int)brk.Attribute("Locked");
                int changed = (int)brk.Attribute("Locked");
                DateTime filetime = (DateTime)brk.Attribute("Filetime");
                DateTime filetime2 = (DateTime)brk.Attribute("Filetime2");
                DateTime time = (DateTime)brk.Attribute("Time");
                string folderType = (string)brk.Attribute("Type");
                string folderId = (string)brk.Attribute("Id");
                string id_Edited = (string)brk.Attribute("Id_Edited");
                int fixo = (int)brk.Attribute("Fixo");
                int descarte = (int)brk.Attribute("Descarte");
                int net = (int)brk.Attribute("Net");
                int breakDur = (int)brk.Attribute("Dur");
                int slots = (int)brk.Attribute("Slots");
                string orig = (string)brk.Attribute("Orig");


                foreach (XElement insNum in brk.Elements())
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
                    //Id,CTA,Source,Type,Title,File,Folder,Text,Composer,Comment,Checked,Err,sErr,HoraAudio,HoraPK,IsAudioFile,Dur,Refr,DurRefr,PtVh,PtMx,MxIni,Intro,PtLoc,Vol,Bitrate,Reg
                    string id = (string)insNum.Attribute("Id");
                    string cta = (string)insNum.Attribute("CTA");
                    string source = (string)insNum.Attribute("Source");
                    string type = (string)insNum.Attribute("Type");
                    string title = (string)insNum.Attribute("Title");
                    string file = (string)insNum.Attribute("File");
                    string folder = (string)insNum.Attribute("Folder");
                    string text = (string)insNum.Attribute("Text");
                    string composer = (string)insNum.Attribute("Composer");
                    string comment = (string)insNum.Attribute("Comment");
                    int check = (int)insNum.Attribute("Checked");
                    int err = (int)insNum.Attribute("Err");
                    string sErr = (string)insNum.Attribute("sErr");
                    DateTime horaAudio = DateTime.ParseExact((string)insNum.Attribute("HoraAudio"), "yyyy-dd-MMTHH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    DateTime horaPK = DateTime.ParseExact((string)insNum.Attribute("HoraPK"), "yyyy-dd-MMTHH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    int isAudioFile = (int)insNum.Attribute("Err");
                    int dur = (int)insNum.Attribute("Dur");
                    int refr = (int)insNum.Attribute("Refr");
                    int durRefr= (int)insNum.Attribute("DurRefr");
                    int ptVh = (int)insNum.Attribute("PtVh");
                    int ptMx = (int)insNum.Attribute("PtMx");
                    int mxIni = (int)insNum.Attribute("MxIni");
                    int intro = (int)insNum.Attribute("Intro");
                    int ptloc = (int)insNum.Attribute("PtLoc");
                    int vol = (int)insNum.Attribute("Vol");
                    int bitrate = (int)insNum.Attribute("Bitrate");
                    int reg = (int)insNum.Attribute("Reg");

                    row.ItemArray = new object[] { breakFolder, ins, locked, changed, filetime, filetime2, time, folderType,
                                                   folderId, id_Edited, fixo, descarte, net, breakDur,slots, orig,
                                                   id, cta, source,type, title, file, folder, text, composer, comment,
                                                   check, err,sErr, horaAudio, horaPK,isAudioFile, dur, refr,
                                                   durRefr,ptVh,ptMx, mxIni, ptloc, vol, bitrate, reg
                    };
                    
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```